# I need help with my bricked tablet!

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, fastboot, unbricking, tablet

I recently rooted my tablet,using kingoroot.I messed up and now my tablet is stuck on the manufacturer logo...If I try to connect it to a pc,it does not recognize it.It is a chinese turbo-x rubik ii tablet,which has an allwinner 33 processor and android 4.4.2.I can't enter recovery because it stucks on the logo and minimal adb and fastboot doesnt recognize it...It would be amazing if someone could help me,as I need the tablet for studying.

Comment: the tools provided by allwinner are [LiveSuit](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-livesuit), [PhoenixSuit](https://androidmtk.com/use-phoenix-suit-flash-firmware), [Phoenix USB Pro](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-phoenix-usb-pro) and [PhoenixCard](https://androidmtk.com/use-phoenixcard-tool)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to unbrick my tablet with PhoenixCard!