# Is it possible to unbrick an Allwinner Android tablet?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, usb, fastboot, unbricking

A few months ago I got my hands on a cheap Allwinner tablet. I wanted to experiment with running Linux on it, but in the process of my experimentation I (stupidly) deleted/overwrote both the /boot and the (I think) /recovery directories.
Surprise surprise, now it won't boot. Won't event display the logo on the screen. Neither `adb devices` nor `fastboot devices` detect it. It only has 2 buttons, the power button and another tiny button on the side of the motherboard. I discovered that if I held both those buttons down while plugging in the usb cable into my computer, `lsusb` detects it:

```
Bus 002 Device 041: ID 1f3a:efe8 Allwinner Technology sunxi SoC OTG connector in FEL/flashing mode
```

dmesg also detects it:

```
[145566.567458] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[145566.708277] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1f3a, idProduct=efe8, bcdDevice= 2.b3
[145566.708292] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Is it possible to get the tablet back to a working state? If so, any pointers to instructions on how to do so are very welcome.
I'm running Arch Linux. Running adb/fastboot as root doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Searching Google for `allwinner flash tool` brings up a lot of pages talking about flashing Allwinner device using "PhoenixSuit" or "LiveSuit". Also some open source programs can be found - have you tested those tools?

Comment: @Robert Thank for the tip; I'm trying to get LiveSuit running on linux. 
I also landed on [this page](https://linux-sunxi.org/FEL/USBBoot). Running `sunxi-fel -l` returned 
`USB device 002:008   Allwinner A64     92c001ba:94104620:78864320:640803cf` 
and `sunxi-fel version` returned 
`AWUSBFEX soc=00001689(A64) 00000001 ver=0001 44 08 scratchpad=00007e00 00000000 00000000`

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224047/i-need-help-with-my-bricked-tablet#comment290801_224047