# Root an Allwinner 100 based tablet with UNlocked bootloader but limited recovery (no TWRP)

Tags: root-access, bootloader, partitions

I have an Allwinner 100 based Android tablet with an *unlocked* bootloader but limited recovery (no TWRP). Now, I want to root it.

I've tried:

- `adb shell` or `adb root` from recovery: returns "closed"
- `adb shell` from started Android: it enters, but of course, no way to get root from here as I don't have `su`
- Trying to extract the partitions, from shell, using
  `dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/blk0.img bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync` says permission denied
- that Chinese tablet does not have "install from zip" option in the recovery
- that tablet does not have any firmware updates from where I could extract `boot.img` to patch it with Magisk

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224047/i-need-help-with-my-bricked-tablet#comment290801_224047

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Robert readback *boot.img* off device was also my first thought, but it's Allwinner Chipset not MTK do you think it's possible anyway (flash tools linked)?

Comment: @alecxs I missed that little detail hidden in the title. I never have seen an Alwinner base device in reality, but I know that there are some Alwinner based Raspberry-alike boards with integrated flash, may be the tools available for these boards also can be used with Android Alwinner devices?